# Adding column to existing tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, ddl

I am working on an Oracle database. I have to add a new column to 2 existing tables.

The tables are, `T_VERIFY_NAME & T_VERIFY_ADDRESS`

Now the new field/column to add is, `UC_VALUE_TYPE (1 char)`.

How can i create a SQL script that'll add the above column to the 2 tables?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you tried searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alter table t_verify_name add (uc_value_type char(1));
alter table t_verify_address add (uc_value_type char(1));
```